# False null reference warning

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I am writing some functions like this in C# along the lines of int.TryParse:

```
public bool TryGetSomeObject(out SomeObject? outObject) 
{
    outObject = GetSomeObject(); // maybe got null reference
    if (outObject != null) 
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (TryGetSomeObject(out SomeObject gotObject)) 
{
   // here all your references to gotObject are underlined as a possible null reference
   // even though we know for a fact gotObject is not null
}
```

My issue is I can't find a elegant way around this, you can write an additional unnecessary null check every time you call TryGetSomeObject or create a pointless empty instance of SomeObject in the function (not always possible) to return in the event of failure and remove the nullable operator on the out value.

Or maybe I should just learn to ignore the underlines in VS...

Comment: @Enigmativity sorted for him. https://dotnetfiddle.net/sQyf1H

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get what was going on. The `if (TryGetSomeObject(out SomeObject gotObject)) ` should clearly be in another method. In any case, I think you're asking the semantic analyser to do too much work here. I think you'll find it isn't going deep enough to understand the link between the returned `bool` and the `SomeObject?`.

Comment: imho I would get rid of the nullable keyword ?

Answer (score -1):

```c#
public bool TryGetSomeObject([NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out SomeObject? outObject)
{
  outObject = GetSomeObject();
  if (outObject != null) 
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis

Comment: I thought this looked so good, but when I put it in VS it doesn't resolve the OP's problem.

Comment: Actually this seems to work in my initial tests try this in VS [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RGBjfv)